# FTP traffic with password attempt

Tags: ftp, wireshark

I had a lab session few days ago on snort and Wireshark. These questions were asked. I needed help with these questions. 
What would be a Wireshark filter to search for FTP traffic with password attempts?
2. The first element of a snort rule is the action. For example action might be: alert. How many action options are possible? (Specify as a number)

Answer (score 0):

Okereke,

Below is a good video showing how you can filter & capture Clear Text Passwords.

[How to  Capture Passwords with Wireshark](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_m-9QXzVHkg)

Second link shows an example of snort rules which you'll find  very  helpful for your assignment:
[Writing Snort Rules](https://paginas.fe.up.pt/~mgi98020/pgr/writing_snort_rules.htm)